# Proof: If $f$ is continuous and $||f||_1$ and $||f||_{\infty}$ are finite, then $||f||_2$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

**Question:**
Prove that if $f$ is continuous and $||f||_1$ and $||f||_{\infty}$ are both finite, then $||f||_2$ is finite.

**Where I'm stuck:**
Okay so I'm trying to come up with examples of where a continuous function would have finite norm for one of these norms but not the others.

Take a domain $(0, \infty)$. For $||\cdot||_\infty$, I have $f(t) = 1$ (or any other constant function). For the other norms, I'm not sure what to do. I want to do something like $f(t) = \frac{1}{t}$, since it's sup-norm would then be infinite, but I'm thinking the integrals would diverge for the other norms too since they start at $t=0$. Maybe, a piecewise function would do it, but I'm not sure how to come up with a function that has finite norm for only one of the norms and keep the function continuous.

Any thoughts?

How would we prove this statement generally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be measureable. The continuity allows us to write sup instead of essup and therefore we have
$$
\int_{\Omega} |f(x)|^2 dx=\int_{\Omega} |f(x)| \cdot |f(x)| dx \leq \sup_{x \in \Omega}|f(x)| \int_{\Omega}|f(x)|dx
$$
Inserting the defintions we see that
$$
||f||_2^2 \leq ||f||_{\infty}||f||_1<\infty
$$
Remark: The continuity basically makes sure the function is measurable.

Comment: this makes perfect sense thank you! i feel silly asking for such a simple proof. Can you think of continuous functions that converge for the 1-norm but not the others, or that converge for the 2-norm but not the others?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705124/convergence-in-l2-does-not-imply-convergence-in-l-infty 
There are many other counterexamples on this site.